# Disable function to enable another one

Tags: function, lua, fivem

Hello sorry for disturbing i am currently working on a Anti cheat on fivem

But I have a little problem in fivem/gta you have default Natives/Functions

Exempel

`IsPedInAnyVehicle(ped, boolean)` -- it returns when a ped is in a vehicle

What I am trying to do is catch the function

like this

```
function IsPedInAnyVehicle(ped, boolean)
   -- i want to put my conditions here and when the conditions fit it accepts the real default 
   --   native/function
end
```

Catching the function and it is blocking the native/default function of the game but now is the question when the condition fits i want to execute the real function/native

I thinked to delete the function thad i made when the conditions fit but idk if thad is possibel
Thx in advance

Neo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply overwrite the function with the new one and keep a reference to the original function so you can use it if your condition is met.

```
function someFunction()
  print("I'm the old function")
end

local backup = someFunction
someFunction = function ()
  if condition then
    backup()
  else
    print("Hey I'm the new function!")
  end
end


someFunction()
condition = true
someFunction()
condition = false
someFunction()
```

prints

```
Hey I'm the new function
I'm the old function
Hey I'm the new function!
```